# Embed a plotly.html plot into a quarto notebook?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, plotly, quarto

I have two local plotly graphs saved as html files - `volcano_plot_1.html` and `volcano_plot_2.html` in the same folder as a `notebook.qmd file`

currently, I'm importing them, and rendering them in the notebook like so:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame(src='r_vs_nr_volcano.html', width=1200, height=600)
```

This generally works fine if I run the command:

`quarto render path/to/notebook/.qmd --to-html`

However, if I try and export this notebook from outside the folder, the plotly graphs no longer render. I've tried using: `embed-resources: True` and `self-contained: true` in the header section of the notebook, However, these also seem to yield no result.

Is there any way I can embed and display these html files into the quarto html output, so that it is self-contained and portable?

As always, any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Having the same issue. You ever get it resolved?

Comment: originally, the volcano_plot_x.html's were rendered from their own .qmd files, I believe I ultimately took the code from both qmd files and placed it in the same qmd file and then rendered it. Realise it's not really a solution but that's how I got around it! :)